# Encode/Decode ContentVersion Rest API Export and Upload

Tags: contentversion, data-migration, simple-salesforce

I’m working on a small python script to export ContentVersion records from one Salesforce org and migrate them into another. I’m using simple-salesforce. I am able to export the ContentVersion and the relayed VersionData. I’m running into issues with figuring out what to do with the VersionData response and what the appropriate decide / encode process is to then resend the content version to the new org. The files are always corrupted and don’t open.

Here's sample code, note I'm doing this in a colab notebook:

```python
#Query Content Files
#GET SOURCE NOTES
content_doc_source_data = source_sf.query_all("SELECT Id, ContentDocumentId, ContentLocation, ContentUrl, Description, FileExtension, FileType, IsLatest, OwnerId, PathOnClient, SharingOption, SharingPrivacy, Title, VersionData FROM ContentVersion WHERE FileType !='SNOTE'")
content_doc_source_data_df = pd.DataFrame(content_doc_source_data['records']).drop(columns='attributes')

content_doc_source_data_df
```

This returns a table, and you can see there's a path for the ContentDoc itself in VersionData.
[image]

So then I'm iterating through that table and querying the VersionData:

```python
import json

headers = {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer %s' % access_token
    }

for index, row in content_doc_source_data_df.iterrows():
  r = requests.request('get', instance_url+'/services/data/v52.0/sobjects/ContentVersion/'+row['Id']+'/VersionData', headers=headers)
  content_doc_source_data_df.at[index, 'File Body'] = r.text
  break

display(content_doc_source_data_df)
```

I then add the file body to the table just so I can interact with it, see picture below:
[image]

I think my question more specifically is, what should I be returning from the response (e.g., text, content, etc.) and then what are the next steps to decode/encode so that I can then insert that file into another Salesforce org.

Comment: Could you add the Python code to your question?

Comment: [SFDMU](https://help.sfdmu.com/full-documentation/add-on-api/export-file-core-add-on-module) does this out of the box. Python: https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce/issues/167

Comment: @FelixvanHove updated the content above to have some of the code I'm using!

Comment: @AndrewCann: Are you getting any response when you are querying version data? can you convert the version data string to base64 string and try.

Comment: @MuzammilBajaria that's what I'm hoping to get guidance on, I am getting data. You can see "File Body" column above. I was looking for guidance on converting it to base64 string.